# I want to make Slideshow with Content beaneath it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 recently i visited this site : [http://www.suprafootwear.com/][1]    


  [1]: http://www.suprafootwear.com/
```

i have see that there is slideshow in the home page (full width slideshow). one of the cool thing about that it slides auto load and also it has slidetext beneath it when click on that i will show that image slideshow. 
so any one can help me figure out how i can make this type of slideshow.
[i had record gif of this slideshow panel for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ3AF.gif)

also they use owl carousel plugin.

[image]

**so i want to make exactly same slideshow with content beneath it**
help me out

thanks

Comment: We don't do coding for you, we help you with your coding, so post a minimal working code snippet for us and we'll try to help to make it work.

Comment: yeah i am working on it. i will post once finished it

Comment: hi i just create a html and css demo. i need jquery to work it out check i create fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Kaash/7zhmd3ju/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  center: true,
  margin: 0,
  callbacks: true,
  URLhashListener: false,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash',
  autoplay: true,
 });
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px !important;
}
.text-tags { text-align:center; }
.text-tags ul { list-style:none; }
.text-tags ul li { display:inline-table; width:20%; border:#000 solid 1px; padding:10px; margin:0px !important;
background-color: #f39c12; }
.text-tags ul li a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'corporate_condensed', sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<section id="demos">
 <div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item" data-hash="one">
   <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hash="two">
   <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hash="three">
   <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/3.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-hash="four">
   <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/4.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="text-tags">
  <ul>
   <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#one">Image 1</a></li> 
   <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#two">Image 2</a></li> 
   <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#three">Image 3</a></li> 
   <li><a class="button secondary url" href="#four">Image 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</section>
```

Check my try out

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q851zfwe/1/

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need **OWL-CAROUSEL**, a wonderful jQuery Slider plugin with number of effects and features. but don't expect complete integration from anyone here, as no one is going to do that. Here is the link http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/demos.html, here you can find the demos and required assets (CSS & JS), download and start working on it..

Comment: yeah i am working to make html blueprint and soon post here

Comment: sure.. that could be great.. :) its a simple integration, you can easily go-through it. All The Best.. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaash/7zhmd3ju/  help me out of that

Comment: Yeah that's great, just give me a reminder tomorrow. I would be glad to help you out, right now I'm not with my machine..

Comment: ok hope to hear from you soon with ease code. check out my question 3 i have jsfiddle as well as code post too. so easy to try on  your machine with local server : ) and make it alive

Comment: @kash here is my try, https://jsfiddle.net/q851zfwe/1/, works pretty good while dragged and dropped in fiddle. but my end works well on click of texts as well.. if you can respond me on my e-mail, i can send you my try out. Thanks..

Comment: you can remark me at, [ameenulla0007 AT ji-mail dot com]